# Select into variables from cte using if oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I need to save values from cte into variables in the procedure.
My example:

```
WITH test_cte AS (
SELECT *
from(
    SELECT date_a,lastName,firstName,birthDate, rank() over(ORDER BY date_a desc) rnk
    FROM test_table a
    join test_table b ON b.id = a.bid 
)a1
WHERE rnk =1)

SELECT count(*) into count_a 
FROM test_table a
join test_table b ON b.id = a.bid
WHERE a.code = code_name;



IF count_a > 0 THEN
    SELECT date_a,lastName,firstName,birthDate
    into date_a_var,lastName_var,firstName_var,birthDate_var
    FROM test_cte;
ELSE 
date_a_var := NULL;
lastName_var := NULL;
firstName_var := NULL;
birthDate_var := NULL;
END IF;
```

but when I try to compile it I'm getting next error:

```
PL / SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

on `FROM test_cte;`

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```sql
-- Start of first SELECT statement.
WITH test_cte AS (
  SELECT *
  from(
    SELECT date_a,lastName,firstName,birthDate, rank() over(ORDER BY date_a desc) rnk
    FROM test_table a
    join test_table b ON b.id = a.bid 
  )a1
  WHERE rnk =1
)
SELECT count(*) into count_a 
FROM test_table a
join test_table b ON b.id = a.bid
WHERE a.code = code_name;
-- End of first SELECT statement.

IF count_a > 0 THEN
  -- Start of second SELECT statement.
  SELECT date_a,lastName,firstName,birthDate
  into date_a_var,lastName_var,firstName_var,birthDate_var
  FROM test_cte;
  -- End of second SELECT statement.
ELSE 
  date_a_var := NULL;
  lastName_var := NULL;
  firstName_var := NULL;
  birthDate_var := NULL;
END IF;
```

It won't work because the `test_cte` only exists for the one statement and when you finish the statement's final `SELECT` statement then it no longer exists for the subsequent statements. *(However, you do not use the sub-query factoring clause [a.k.a. CTE] in the `SELECT` for that statement so it is not clear why you need the `WITH` clause.)*

Instead of trying to use `COUNT`, just get the data and handle the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception if it occurs (also, from Oracle 12, you don't need to use `RANK` and can use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` instead):

```sql
DECLARE
  date_a_var    test_table.date_a%TYPE;
  lastName_var  test_table.lastname%TYPE;
  firstName_var test_table.firstname%TYPE;
  birthDate_var test_table.birthdate%TYPE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT date_a,
           lastName,
           firstName,
           birthDate
    INTO   date_a_var,
           lastName_var,
           firstName_var,
           birthDate_var
    FROM   test_table a
           join test_table b ON b.id = a.bid 
    ORDER BY date_a DESC
    FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      date_a_var    := NULL;
      lastName_var  := NULL;
      firstName_var := NULL;
      birthDate_var := NULL;
  END;

  -- Continue processing
END;
```

*(Note: You may also get a `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception if there are duplicate dates. Either use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` or, before Oracle 12, the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function.)*